# Neighbourhood Aggregation query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are evaluating whether to use graph database like neo4j or not in our project. For evaluation we need to know whether a particular neighborhood aggregation query is possible in neo4j.
Here is the graph design we are thinking.
We have 2 kind of nodes as follows
- User
- Movie

And there exists an edge only between User node and movie node. A node exists if the User has rated the movie.

We want to write a query that calculates the star rating of all movies based on the aggregation that we would do on the neighbors which is users.

e.g User A rated movie m1 as 2 and m2 as 3
User B rated movie m1 as 1 and m3 as 5

So the result set would be

```
m1 - (2+1)/2 = 1.5
m2 - 3/1 = 3
m3 - 5/1 = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

That is very simple:

```
MATCH (:User)-[r:RATED]->(movie:Movie)
RETURN movie, AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating;
```

The assumed data model has `User` and `Movie` nodes, and `RATED` relationships containing the `rating` property.

(Also, since in this data model only `User` nodes can rate movies, you can simplify the `MATCH` pattern to just: `()-[r:RATED]->(movie:Movie)`, which will execute faster.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer cybersam. Appreciated. Just a follow up question. Lets say rating is dynamic which keeps on changing every time we want to calculate the avg_rating. So idea is that we get the ratings every time from some other database and feed into graph database dynamically. Is that possible?

Comment: Every time you run the query, it will see all the committed changes at that time. For more info, [see here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/transactions/#transactions-isolation).